# Is QAM the best way to do this?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Sorry about this noob question, because I never work with matlab and signal processing before.
Here is what I want to do: I have a fixed length of byte array X, now I want to encode it to a sound file, I also want this process to be reversible, which means the sound can be converted back to X with no error. I searched online, and found the following code:

```
M = 16; 
x = randint(5000,1,M); 
y=modulate(modem.qammod(M),x);
```

My question is that, is QAM the best way to do this? and how to use it? A little bit code example will be really appreciated, Thank you!

update#1: I tried to output y by sound(y), but matlab does not allow me to do so, it says I can only output floating numbers. How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: What are your requirements for this transmission system? Must it be noise resistant, what does the transmission channel look like, how many bit/seconds do you need to transmit and so on? There are many ways to achieve what you want. Your example above will probably work if you just need to save a sound file and get the data back from that, but if you want to transmit the audio over the air or a telephone line or something like that, it's a completly different matter.

Comment: @KlausCPH I will probably need to transmit the audio over the air, the bit rate does not matter, so what should I look at? thank you

Comment: @KlausCPH btw, my idea is to put simple ECC into the byte array to make it noise resistant, is that possible? thank you

Comment: I just need to transmit about 129-bit data

Comment: You may want to ask about the theory side of this question on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @mtrw thank you, but I don't have any related background, so I'd better stay here and try to make my code working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to transmit over the air, you have quiet a lot of work in front of you I think. The most difficult problem to solve in a telecommunications system is often synchronization, meaning that your receiver will have to know where the QAM symbols are placed in time. This is not easy. If you choose to go ahead I agree with mtrw that you should try dsp.stackexchange.com.

Try for example to imaging a simple modulation scheme where each bit is converted to a short piece of sine with the frequency depending on whether the bit is one or zero. How would you go about decoding this on the receiver end? You need to detect the onset of the first bit and have some self maintaining clock running for synchronization on the receiver to find bits in case they do not change, aka a PLL (Phase Locked Loop). This could possibly be made easier by using manchester coding, but you would still have to do quite a lot to get it running.

As you see, there are no easy solutions when you leave the save Matlab harbor :-)

Best regards